# Sitecore User Group Aug 2018 Meetup - Queen City, Manchester, NH

Tags: discussion, status-completed, community-event

We are delighted to announce the August meetup of the Queen City Sitecore User Group.

Two excellent presentation are lined up for this SUG:

- Sitecore and MVC A-to-Z - Corey Smith, Sitecore MVP and Solutions Architect at Perficient
- Sitecore Token Manager - Jeff Darchuk, Sitecore MVP and Solutions Architect at Perficient

Join us for food, excellent company -- not to mention loads of terrible albeit obligatory puns -- and great cheer as we watch presentations on all things Sitecore!

Date & Time (EST):- Wednesday, Aug, 22, 2018 6:00 PM

Date & Time (UTC):- Wednesday, Aug, 22, 2018 10:00 PM

Venue:- SilverTech Inc, 196 Bridge Street, Manchester, NH 03104

[Click here for more details and RSVP](https://www.meetup.com/Queen-City-Sitecore-User-Group/events/253545731/).

Comment: Community Promotion is active

Comment: Thanks @MarkCassidy